# IIS 7 Redirect using regular expression

Tags: regex, iis

We currently have a wordpress blog running under a sub domain http:// blog.domain.com. That site is also currently running via reverse proxy as http:// www.domain.com/blog that points to the original subdomain site.

Currently both sites are running correctly but the issue we have is that we want the sub domain site to redirect to the reversed proxy site and not render. We only want the site to render as http:// www.domain.com/blog. I have been attempting to use the URL Rewrite in IIS 7 on a server 2008 machine.

I think the issue I am having is with the regular expression. I tried using -- ^(blog.)* -- and when I test it in IIS it returns that it matches (blog.domainname.com) but the site itself does not redirect when I open it in a browser. I'm not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /></rule>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /> </rule>
        <rule name="redirect to /blog" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(blog.)*" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="http:// www.domainname.com/blog" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is probably that your rewrite rules are not running when you hit that URL. 
Make sure that it's actually mapped to that site.</strike>

Sorry, I just noticed that your rule is not enabled:

```
<rule name="redirect to /blog" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
```

You'd have to modify the enabled attribute to True.

Comment: I went and updated the code so that the rule is enable and the site is still not redirecting. The code I included is the web.config file in the sites root folder. How can I confirm that it is mapped to this website?

Comment: I think your current setup is redirecting twice, once from your subdomain to your domain and then back. Could you check with a tool like fiddler to see wether it's redirecting or not? Alternatively, I could check it for you if you can pass me the website.